# Chord transitions

Tags: chord-progressions

In A Nightingale Sang In Berkeley Square, fake book notation a D13(#11) chord is followed by /C chord.  This is an awkward transition. How is this /C change for D13(#11), played on piano?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming by /C it means a D13#11/C, play D, F#, (A), C, B and G# between the hands, with D as the root, and then drop the left hand lowest note to the C just below.Leave out the A if you want, and put the C and B in the first chord as far apart as you can. It doesn't have to be so in the slash chord, as the lowest note is C. Play around with the voicing till you find one that sounds good to you.